# what is wrong with my code using FrameLayout in setting UI for 2048?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, layout

i am new to android studio
i just started learning it week ago
i am trying to make 2048 to practice android studio.
i tried to make UI
i am taking a framelayout and in that i am taking 16 (4x4) framelayout to use them as grids to show
in diplay of android studio it is fine to see the ui but when i run the app in mobile i am not getting the same ui as expected.
please help me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.lol.MainActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_p1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:text="Player 1: 0"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_p2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_p1"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:text="Player 2: 0"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_reset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="33dp"
            android:text="reset"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="33dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!--        first row-->
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:background="#FFEB3B">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/T_00"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/T_01"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/T_02"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="205dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/T_03"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="305dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton" />

            <!--            second row-->
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/T_10"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/T_11"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/T_12"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="205dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/T_13"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="305dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton" />

            <!--            third row-->
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/T_20"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="205dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/T_21"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="205dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/T_22"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="205dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="205dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/T_23"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="305dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="205dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton" />

            <!--            fourth row-->
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/T_30"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="305dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/T_31"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="305dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/T_32"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="205dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="305dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/T_33"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="305dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="305dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton" />


        </FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

in design i am getting like

[image]

but i in mobile i am getting as below
[image]

can anyone please help me out.

Comment: You have to calculate cell size programmatically and set size to all cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use grid layout. Gridlayout is perfect for you in this case. If you still want to stick to frame layout, consider adding margin to linearlayout.

Comment: thank you for the reply, well i dont if i can use gridlayout i never used it ,
can you whst margin i have to keep